# Will this series converge? $\sum \frac {1/2 + (-1)^n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Will this series converge?
$\sum \frac {1/2 + (-1)^n}{n}$

MY Try:  Dirichilet  , Abel , libnitz rules can not be used.   $\sum \frac {1/2 + (-1)^n}{n} = \sum \frac {1}{2n} +  \sum\frac {(-1)^n}{2n} $. Is it possible to write in that way? If yes the how?

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Yes, split the **partial sum** and then take the limit. One piece diverges and the other one is convergent.

Comment: As @RobertZ said, the right part is the alternating harmonic series, which is equal to $-\log{2}$. The left part is half of the harmonic series, which diverges, so the whole sum will diverge.

Comment: So partial sums can be rearranged or grouped? @RobertZ

Comment: Yes, there is no issue with regrouping of *partial sums*. However, note that if one partial sum happens to go to infinity and the other to negative infinity, then this alone does not suffice to make conclusions about their sum.

Comment: Yea I got it.@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Can the terms rearranged in partial sum@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Can the terms rearranged in partial sum@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Can the terms rearranged in partial sum@RobertZ

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum\frac{1/2+(-1)^n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n}+\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
I believe that the first summation is called the harmonic series and is divergent whilst the second summation is convergent